# Take elements from a list based on two criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, conditional

I am trying to take elements from a list of tuples using 2 criteria. 
An example of the list is:

```
list={{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}
```

And I need to take the elements that contain one value $=1$ 
and a second value $\neq1$. Thus at the end, I will have

```
    list2={{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}
```

I`ve been trying using select as

```
list2 = Flatten[Table[Select[list[[i]], # == 1 &, 2]], {i, 1,5}], 1];
```

but the problem is that the values $=1$ do not have a "fixed column". Is there a way to do this avoiding an "if" statement?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Select[list, Count[#, 1] == 1&]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Also

```
Pick[list, Lookup[Counts /@ list, 1, 0], 1]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

And alternative ways to use `Cases`:

```
Cases[{OrderlessPatternSequence[1, Except[1]]}]@list
Cases[_?(Counts[#][1] == 1&)]@list
```

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Comment: Oh, Thanks!. Do you know if the "Select" case can be used as a list?, eg, list[[i]].  This, because I have to track with the case, was not eliminated, For example, at the end, I will have `element2-{-1,1}`

Comment: @mors, the output from all methods is a list.So, using `selected = Select[list, Count[#, 1] == 1&]`, you can access its parts as, say, `selected[[2]]` (which is `{1, -1}`) and `selected[[2]] - {-1,1}` gives `{2, -2}`.

Comment: Thank you, I said it because every element in `list` is the output of a matrix, so my final goal is to construct `llist2`with the elements that were not erased from  `list` and the name of the matrix that they correspond. e.g list2={{mat2-{1-1}, mat3-{-1,1}]. So I was wondering if I can use something as
`list2 = Flatten[
   Table[ToString[
     tabmatrices[[i]] <> "-" <> 
      ToString[   Select[list[[i]], Count[#, 1] == 1&]   ]], {i, 1,5}], 1];`

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) instead:

```
Cases[list, {1,Except[1]}|{Except[1],1}]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Answer (score 6):

Paranoid version of kglr's `Count` solution:

```
Select[list, Total[Boole[PossibleZeroQ[# - 1]] & /@ #] == 1 &]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following construction:

```
 lst = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}
 Cases[lst, {x_, y_} /; (x == 1 && y != 1) || (y == 1 && x != 1)]
```

Which may be more helpful in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

Just a variant:

```
Reap[Sow[#, Count[#, 1]] & /@ list, 1][[2, 1]]
```

yields: {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Answer (score 2):

```
l = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}};
```

Another way using `Pick`:

```
Pick[l, Abs@*Subtract @@@ Map[Boole@*(# != 1 &), l, {2}], 1]

(*{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}*)
```

Or simpler using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[l, {a_ ..}]

(*{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[l, {s : {a_, b_} /; a != b} :> s]

(*{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{4, 5}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}};
```

Pre-define pattern for better comparability

```
p = {Except[1] ..} | {1, 1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[list, {p}]
```

{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[list, p :> Nothing, All]
```

{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[list, Position[list, p, 1]]
```

{{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[list,MatchQ[{OrderlessPatternSequence[1,Except[1]]}]]

(* {{-1,1},{1,-1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}

f = Times @@ # == 1 &;

DeleteCases[list, _?f]

Select[list, Not@*f]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}}